# How to send a list in different line in node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm a new guy in Node.js and now met some problems in development.
I have a code here:

```
var arr = ["red","blue","green"];
res.json(arr)
```

and the output is like this:

```
red,blue,green
```

How can I do to make it display as:

```
red
blue
green
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: If you're displaying the result in the browser and want to control how it looks, use HTML, not JSON.  Then, you can control the entire display using all the powers of HTML.  If you're not displaying it in a browser, then what are you displaying it in?

Comment: "and the output is like this" — It isn't. The output will be an HTTP response with some JSON in the body. You seem to have left out a significant portion of the code from your [mcve].